# siunitx: combination of (-0.123) and post text as 1.234*** gives useless result

Tags: siunitx

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=-1.3,
                  table-space-text-pre ={(-},  % hasn't  effect ?
                  table-space-text-post={***},% hasn't  effect ?
                  input-symbols={( )},
                  explicit-sign,
                  parse-numbers=false,
                 ]|}
\hline
  1.248\textsuperscript{***}  \\
(-0.124)                        \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It gives

[image]

Is there a way to obtain usable result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue can be solved by putting the parentheses (pre and post part) in braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=-1.3,
                  table-space-text-pre ={(},
                  table-space-text-post={\textsuperscript{***}},
                  explicit-sign,
                 ]|}
\hline
  1.248\textsuperscript{***} \\
{(}-0.124{)}                 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It compiles without warnings about overfull `\hbox`es.

> [image: Result]

The curly braces protect the parentheses symbols for being parsed as uncertainty symbols. The input symbols for the uncertainty can be changed to avoid the curly braces in the table body:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=-1.3,
                  table-space-text-pre ={(},
                  table-space-text-post={\textsuperscript{***}},
                  explicit-sign,
                  input-open-uncertainty={[},
                  input-close-uncertainty={]},
                 ]|}
\hline
  1.248\textsuperscript{***} \\
(-0.124)                     \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you want to get rid of the additional braces in the table body, then
the parentheses

Comment: this works!!! I very like the second solution, it is very convenient at table writing :-)